# How to get the latest released tag name in github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to try to implement that whenever I make a new release in github, actions will automatically publish the corresponding release to pypi for me, but this requires me to get the latest release number.

I've tracked some of stackoverflow's related question, but embarrassingly none of them work for me. For example in [#16241](https://github.community/t/how-to-get-just-the-tag-name/16241)

My error message is:

#### Set output

```
Run echo ::set-output name=tag::${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}
::set-output
name=tag::
```

#### Test

```
Run echo $RELEASE_VERSION
Write-Output: D:\a\_temp\7fa75053-482a-4be6-bec1-6b0f60cdf855.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  echo
     |  ~~~~
     | Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: InputObject.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I'm running on a windows vm, is there something wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer on How to get Tag Name in GitHub Actions

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
jobs:
  github-example-tags:
    steps:
     - name: GitHub Tag Name example
       run: |
         echo "Tag name from GITHUB_REF_NAME: $GITHUB_REF_NAME"
         echo "Tag name from github.ref_name: ${{  github.ref_name }}"
```

See

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by setting your publish workflow to run on the following event:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    # Sequence of patterns matched against refs/tags
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Push events to matching v*, i.e. v1.0, v20.15.10
```

Then you'll be able to get the tag itself with the `github.ref` context in your job.